# Django. Unique option for model field doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I set option 'primary_key' for object Name field. After that I create tables for models via command 'syncdb'. Then set 'unique' option to True. Ran 'syncdb'. But when I work with my object form there is no any uniqueness.
If I work with add form I can specify already existing name and in result it will effect on object with this name and no any unique restriction. 
But I need in add form only create objects and if there is already exist object with that name the unique restriction error will be showed.
So how exactly 'unique' option work and what should I do to work add form in my way?

**Edit1:**

Forgot to say that this is all about admin site.

Model:

```
class Rfxdigest(models.Model):
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.crm_id
        crm_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column=u'CRM_ID', primary_key=True, unique=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Creation_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column=u'Creation_date', default=datetime.now()) # Field name made lowercase.
        Close_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, db_column=u'Close_date', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Name = models.TextField(db_column=u'Name') # Field name made lowercase.
        StatusReasonId = models.ForeignKey(Rfxstatusreason, db_column=u'StatusReasonID') # Field name made lowercase.
        BriefDescription = models.TextField(db_column=u'Brief_description', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Notes = models.TextField(db_column=u'Notes', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        POI = models.TextField(db_column=u'POI', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        USP = models.TextField(db_column=u'USP', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Client_problem = models.TextField(db_column=u'Client_problem', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Currency = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'Currency', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Ballpark_begin = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'Ballpark_begin', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Ballpark_end = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'Ballpark_end', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Estimate = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'Estimate', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Ballpark_for_processing = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'Ballpark_for_processing', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Applied_efforts = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'Applied_efforts', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Coordinator = models.TextField(db_column=u'Coordinator', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Analyst = models.TextField(db_column=u'Analyst', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        TechExpert = models.TextField(db_column=u'TechExpert', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        SalesPerson = models.TextField(db_column=u'SalesPerson', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        LeadQuality = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'LeadQuality', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Time_frame_is_realistic = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'Time_frame_is_realistic', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        RFX_does_match_our_expertise_domain = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'RFX_does_match_our_expertise_domain', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Have_resources_available = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'Have_resources_available', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        RFX_is_the_competitors_follow_up = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'RFX_is_the_competitors_follow_up', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        RFX_is_the_follow_up_from_our_client = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'RFX_is_the_follow_up_from_our_client', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Have_competitive_edge_over_others = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'Have_competitive_edge_over_others', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Chances_of_winning_proposal_are_less_than_30_percent = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'Chances_of_winning_proposal_are_less_than_30_percent', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Customer_has_own_budget = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'Customer_has_own_budget', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        RFX_has_potential_for_followup = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'RFX_has_potential_for_followup', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        FP = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'FP', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        TM_DT = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'TM_DT', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        RFX_is_technically_interested = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'RFX_is_technically_interested', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Customer_provides_good_communication_level = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'Customer_provides_good_communication_level', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        The_client_is_well_known_company = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'The_client_is_well_known_company', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Requirements_are_well_clarified = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'Requirements_are_well_clarified', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Project_may_represent_conflict_of_interests = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'Project_may_represent_conflict_of_interests', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        RFX_is_the_result_of_company_campaign = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'RFX_is_the_result_of_company_campaign', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        RFX_is_an_unexpected_opportunity = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'RFX_is_an_unexpected_opportunity', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        RFX_is_part_of_multiproject_work = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'RFX_is_part_of_multiproject_work', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Had_conf_call_with_customer = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'Had_conf_call_with_customer', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Sent_vision = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'Sent_vision', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Sent_BP = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'Sent_BP', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Added_new_initially_unspecified_features = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'Added_new_initially_unspecified_features', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        Proposed_different_platform = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'Proposed_different_platform', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
        class Meta:
            db_table = u'RFXDigest'
            verbose_name = 'RFX Digest'
```

**Edit2**

Just created new DB and run syncdb on it. Model has 'unique=True'. Nothing changed. But in both DB these models' uniqueness worked well:

```
class Rfxstatusreason(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.statusname
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column=u'ID', primary_key=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    statusname = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column=u'StatusName') # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'RFXStatusReason'
        verbose_name = 'RFX Status Reason'

class Rfxclosereasondescription(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.closereason
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column=u'ID', primary_key=True, auto_created=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    closereason = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column=u'CloseReason') # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'RFXCloseReasonDescription'
        verbose_name = 'RFX Close Reason Description'
```

Could it be that problem is about IntegerField and CharField?

Answer (score 0):

`syncdb` does not update the table - [see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb), as you have already created the table you can either

- Drop the table and run `syncdb` again
- Alter the table manually

Comment: Altered the table manually - added unique key constraint for name. No any effect.

Comment: @sunprophit since it works for everyone else, perhaps you might consider giving us a clue by posting your models, form and view code.

Comment: Edited my answer. It is all about admin site so form and view are almost default. Only some changes in admin to customize object form.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use `unique`

For Example:

```
crm_id = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True, primary_key = True)
```

Don't Forget To Drop The Table Then `syncdb` Again.

Comment: I can't change uniqueness of the field in the DB manually? I mean already did it and set unique to True. Nothing changed.

Comment: Django Can't Understand That You Change The Column. You Must Update It. If You Have Data In Your Table You Can Use South.

Comment: Ok. Edited my question. I created new DB and run syncdb on it.

Comment: Where Is Your Problem? In Admin Panel?

Comment: Actually I Don't See Any unique = True. You Must Add It To Your model field.

Comment: Sorry just forget update model in question. By the way in model 'Rfxstatusreason' there is no unique property, only primary_key and uniqueness still work good.

Comment: Actually I Run Your Code. It's Work. But I Remove db_column And primary_key And Add unique = True, I Drop Database Then Create It Again, Syncdb. I Test It In My Admin Panel And It Works.

Comment: So if you create new rfx with existing id - existing rfx won't update?

Comment: You Can't Create rfx Object With The Same id. Because id Is Unique. But Can Update Selected rfx Object. If You Change id And It Isn't Exist, Then id Can Update Too.

Comment: As I wrote in question the problem is that I can specify existing id in RFXDigest add-form and update existing RFXDigest. And unique option does't help me with that. And I see that with IntegerField unique works good, but not with CharField.